# display records which are in another model in django admin

Tags: mysql, django, django-admin

I have models like

```
class Customers(models.Model):
     m1 = models.EmailField()

class Requests(models.Model):
     m2 = models.EmailField()

class CustomersRequests(Customers):
     class Meta:
          proxy = True
```

My question is I want to display unique emails in CustomersRequests admin such way that, those customer emails in Requests model.

For example:

### Customers

v1@xyz.com
v2@xyz.com
v3@xyx.com

### Requests

v1@xyz.com
v1@xyz.com
v3@xyx.com
v1@xyz.com
I want only follwing records in CustomersRequests
v1@xyz.com
v3@xyx.com
I write queryset in CustomersRequests to distinct records but mysql database gives DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend?

Then How I can display unique records ? without disturbing the Customers and Requests models?

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Choosing the fields inside `.distinct()` is only supported on Postgres.

To make this work on other backends, you may need a different strategy. I have not tested these, but you might try:

1. `.annotate().order_by('field')`
2. `.order_by('field').distinct()`
3. Removing duplicates via Python after the queryset is returned.